# How do I get the addresses from the Ganache?

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts, remix, ganache

I am trying to implement a virtual Smart Voting in Remix IDE.

I want to get the remaining 99 addresses from the Ganache to create an iteration and have them register at polling stations and then vote.

How do I get these addresses?

[photo from Ganache](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jM41S.png)

Comment: What other tools are you using? Truffle? Ethers? hardhat? Could you also share what you've tried already, if anything?

Comment: I am using Truffle Suite [https://trufflesuite.com/ ] for the Ganache. I haven't made anything worthwhile.

Comment: [this](https://trufflesuite.com/docs/truffle/getting-started/interacting-with-your-contracts/#making-a-transaction) might help. You'd simply call `web3.getAccounts()` where `web3` would be a `Web3` object initialized with your Ganache url

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to Martijn, you can also use ganache-cli package and specifiy the number of accounts you want!!!

```
const ganache = require('ganache-cli');
const Web3 =  require('web3');

const options = { a: 100 }; // NO OF ACCOUNTS
const provider = ganache.provider(options);
const web3 = new Web3(provider);
const accounts = web3.getAccounts();
```

you can use following docs to install ganache-cli -> https://www.npmjs.com/package//ganache-cli